# Display CPT description on archive.php pages for all CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

i'd like to show the CPT description on the archive.php page but it'd like to do it dynamically for all CPT's. I mean without specifying the current type myself. Something like the_archive_description but for CPT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 4.9.

```
if ( get_the_post_type_description()) {

echo get_the_post_type_description();

}
```

redeclaring the function will crash WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_the_post_type_description() {
    $post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );

    if ( is_array( $post_type ) ) {
        $post_type = reset( $post_type );
    }

    $post_type_obj = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

    // Check if a description is set.
    if ( isset( $post_type_obj->description ) ) {
        $description = $post_type_obj->description;
    } else {
        $description = '';
    }
    return apply_filters( 'get_the_post_type_description', $description, $post_type_obj );
}
```

Here is a future function of WP v4.9 that retrieves the description for a post type archive and returns (string) The post type description. I think it can do the trick for you.

Comment: NVM i had to echo the function, all good, works!